# Adding a video to a page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to embed video in a page by only using jQuery.
basically i look for a code that if you run in the console embeds a video from a URL to the page.
please provide me with some sample code. Thank you

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use some HTML to create the DOM elements but here is an example using the hardcoded HTML from: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_video_html5_4

To attach the video to the body using jQuery you would do this:

```
$('body').append('<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay><source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg"><source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"><source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm"><object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240"><embed width="320" height="240" src="movie.swf"></object></video>');
```

Please post additional information if there is something more specific you would like answered.